# onloadeddata/ onload/ onerror events not firing for object tag (when render the pdf files)

Tags: html, dom

I'm writing a program to view a pdf on the HTML page.
I'm using object tag for this purpose

```
<object width="400" height="400" data="helloworld.pdf" onloadeddata="alert('done')">Not Found
</object>
```

I'm getting 2 issues here.

1) Chrome doesn't display the "Not Found" text

2) onloadeddata / onload/ onevent function doesn't fire

Actually, if the file does not exist I want to display a not found message
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Is pdf considered a media file? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadeddata

Comment: @Kaiido onload event also not working

Comment: @mplungjan if the pdf is not a media file, then how can we trigger a function after pdf load?

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=object+onload+pdf+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @mplungjan that question doesn't have the correct answer, the answers are not working.

Comment: "not working" is not a useful statement. They claim onload should work. It does not work for you. Why not? Errors in the console? onerror does that work if the file does not exist?

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks, ya onerror event is working when the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Hmm... [Could repro](https://plnkr.co/edit/QzxjiZgaxoa5gWNU8lSL?p=preview)... Indeed Chrome seems to not fire the event when they do load the object's data through a plugin... But for what it's worth, they do if you load the pdf in an `<iframe>` instead...

Comment: Works if you use an iframe as suggested in some of the links in the google search I suggested https://plnkr.co/edit/DF0p26QlMZ4AryZBE9g3?p=preview